# Prevent Dll injection from an Dll C++

Tags: c++, dll, hook, code-injection

I have some doubts about anti dll injection in C++.
I have a game C++ based, Im having problems with hackers with dll injection.
Then i need to prevent it.

I find notify hook there from there:

[MSDN - Notification Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h1h6ty%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

But i dont have idea how to use it.

Its is possible notify hook to prevent dll injection?

How its possible? (With and example better).

Can be from dll? (With example better).

Thanks for read that post.

PS: sorry for my english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Dll Injection from Dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450113/prevent-dll-injection-from-dll)

Comment: Those are delay load notifications generated by the /DELAYLOAD library. They have nothing to do with injection.

Comment: Note that there are all sorts of legitimate reasons why DLLs might want to get loaded in your process - from needing to suddenly change the language of the OS, hotpatching (Windows Update) sometimes does this, Application compatability shimming when your application gets patched by Microsoft to work on Windows8 for example, or when the user's antivirus wants to come into your process to have a look around. Preventing all of these actions can substantially screw over the user, and they might not thank you for it - particularly since loading a DLL into your process isn't the only way to hack it.

Answer (score 6):

Forget it, unless you do very sophisticated things, it's not going to work. By sophisticated I mean something like the code obfuscation, anti-debugging technology used in Skype. Just look at [this talk](http://www.secdev.org/conf/skype_BHEU06.handout.pdf).

You can spend a ton of time on trying to prevent DLL injection, in the end somebody will spend less time than you and circumvent your protection. I think the time would be better invested in an architecture that's more secure and tamperproof (ie calculating scores on the server, etc).

It's a cat and mouse game you can't win.

Comment: Im using Unreal Engine as graphic core, theys touch the code whit dll to set unreal properties for example wall transparency or characters textures then like an wall hack or something like that and the more used its an hack than auto aim the head from maya map. Can be debugged?, By the way i guess its better block any api trying to access the process than debug that part because everytime you can see many hacks.

Comment: What about that? [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5178/DLL-Injection-and-function-interception-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but I will briefly answer it in better form for anyone who does happen to stumble upon it magically after a proper response.

You cannot fully prevent code injection from within your own process, but you can try to do some tricks without interception of other processes. It is not recommended because you need to have experience and knowledge with lower-level tasks, especially to get it working properly and not prevent functionality of your own software, however...

Asynchronous Procedure Calls (APC) is an implementation from the Windows Kernel. It is primarily used for code injection into other running processes, Windows uses it a lot itself for a variety of things such as notifications being sent to specific processes. When a user-mode process calls QueueUserApc (KERNEL32), NtQueueApcThread (NTDLL) will be invoked. NtQueueApcThread (NTDLL) will perform a system call which will cause NtQueueApcThread (NTOSKRNL) to be invoked, which is not exported by NTOSKRNL - for anyone wondering, NTOSKRNL is the Windows Kernel, and a system-call is nothing more than a transition from user-mode to kernel-mode since the Native API System Routines exist in kernel-mode memory, NTDLL routines for NTAPI are system call stubs which direct control up to the Windows Kernel. When NtQueueApcThread (NTOSKRNL) is called, it'll use KeInitializeApc and KeInsertQueueApc (both do happen to be exported by NTOSKNL). When the APC is actually issued to the targeted process, KiUserApcDispatcher (NTDLL) will be locally called within the process, unless the APC is performed in a more extensive manner to bypass this activity (99% of the time it will not be prevented). This means that you have an oppertunity to intercept this behavior and prevent APC injection into your own process with one single local hook in your own process, via byte-patching (also known as "inline hooking") KiUserApcDispatcher, exported by NTDLL. The only problem which you will face is that it is undocumented and this is not officially supported by Microsoft; you'll need to figure out how the parameters work and how to prevent the callback routine from blocking off genuine requests which are needed to provide functionality for your own software. This will however include prevention of kernel-mode APC injection, not just user-mode attacks.

There are many ways to inject code into a process, and APC is simply one of them. Another common method would be through remote thread creation. When a user-mode process attacks another process via remote thread creation, it'll typically call CreateRemoteThread (KERNEL32). This will lead down to RtlCreateUserThread (NTDLL), and RtlCreateUserThread will call NtCreateThreadEx (NTDLL). NTDLL will perform a system call and then NtCreateThreadEx (non-exported routine from the Windows Kernel) will be invoked in kernel-mode memory. In the end, the targeted process will have LdrInitializeThunk locally invoked, and RtlUserThreadStart will also be invoked locally. Both of these routines are exported by NTDLL. This is a same scenario as with APC... You can patch LdrInitializeThunk locally, however you must do it properly to prevent genuine functionality within your own software.

These two techniques are not full-proof, there is no "full-proof" solution. There are many ways to inject code into a process, and there are very sophisticated methods to bypass said solutions from myself. Anti-Virus software has been battling anti-RCE/self-protection for as long as I can remember, as has Anti-Cheat systems. You should look into kernel-mode device driver development as well, it'll allow you to register kernel-mode callbacks which can help you out.

The first callback you should look into is [ObRegisterCallbacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558692(v=vs.85).aspx). It allows you to receive a Pre-operation callback notification whenever NtOpenProcess is called from the Windows Kernel. This means that user-mode processes will also trigger it, since NtOpenProcess ends up being called in kernel-mode after NTDLL makes the system-call. I cannot remember specifically if the callback APIs are triggered in the NtOpenProcess stub itself or if it goes deeper into Ob* kernel-mode only routines, but you can check at ease with WinDbg with remote kernel debugging, or Interactive Disassembler (target ntoskrnl.exe and use the symbolic links provided by Microsoft). ObRegisterCallbacks supports notifications for both handle creation & duplication for the process and the processes' threads, you can strip access rights you don't want permitted for the requested handle.

The second callback you should look into would be [PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutineEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn957857(v=vs.85).aspx). This callback routine will allow you to receive a notification whenever a new thread creation occurs on the system; you can filter it out for your own process and if a rogue thread is created, terminate the thread.

The third callback you should look into would be [PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutineEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt826267(v=vs.85).aspx). This callback will provide a notification whenever a new module is loaded into a process; once again, you can filter for your own process. If you detect a rogue module, you can attempt to have your process call LdrUnloadDll (NTDLL) targeting the base address of the newly loaded image, however the reference count for the module needs to be 0 for it to be unloaded. In that case, you can try "hacky" methods like calling NtUnmapViewOfSection/NtFreeVirtualMemory. Bear in mind, if you mess up the rogue loaded module and it has set memory byte patches to redirect execution flow to its own routines, unless you restore them, your process will crash when they are referenced.

These are some ideas, commonly the ones typically used. Kernel-Mode callbacks are very popular among security software and anti-cheat software. As for thread creation, you'll be interested in mitigating this as much as possible -> if you only look for rogue DLL loads then you'll miss out on reflective DLL loading. Also remember of the other code injection methods, like thread hijacking, shared window memory exploitation with ROP chain call exploitation, DLL patching on-disk, etc.