# how to block dll injection using a Blackllist/by identifying a dll uniquely?

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, dll, dll-injection

I Have been currently assigned to write a piece of code that will determine if a dll is blacklisted and if so it should not be allowed to load. Google Chrome has this functionality, so I checked Google chrome's code, and saw that they maintain an array of blacklisted dll's from which they protect themselves. I tried some other things like I tried to change the blocked dll's import table, name of dll and many other stuff and then tried to inject it into chrome, but somehow chrome is able to uniquely identify that the dll being injected is a blacklisted dll and prevents it from happening.

Does anyone has any ideas or pointers as to how this can be achieved??

Thanks,
Deepak :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Dll injection from an Dll C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450372/prevent-dll-injection-from-an-dll-c)

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that they maintain a whitelist, rather than a blacklist, which is why your modifications to assemblies still did not cause the dll to load.

Edit: From your comment, this is in fact not the case!
It looks like they maintain a blacklist and do some [arcane invocation](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome_elf/blacklist/blacklist.cc&l=24) of NtMapViewOfSection to prevent the dll load (which makes me thankful I never have to use Windows API):

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
// Interception of NtMapViewOfSection within the current process.
// It should never be called directly. This function provides the means to
// detect dlls being loaded, so we can patch them if needed.
SANDBOX_INTERCEPT NTSTATUS WINAPI BlNtMapViewOfSection64(
    HANDLE section, HANDLE process, PVOID *base, ULONG_PTR zero_bits,
    SIZE_T commit_size, PLARGE_INTEGER offset, PSIZE_T view_size,
    SECTION_INHERIT inherit, ULONG allocation_type, ULONG protect);
#endif
```

```
// Replace the default NtMapViewOfSection with our patched version.
#if defined(_WIN64)
  NTSTATUS ret = thunk->Setup(::GetModuleHandle(sandbox::kNtdllName),
                              reinterpret_cast(&__ImageBase),
                              "NtMapViewOfSection",
                              NULL,
                              &blacklist::BlNtMapViewOfSection64,
                              thunk_storage,
                              sizeof(sandbox::ThunkData),
                              NULL);
```

---

Other than Chromium's approach there are also a number of 3rd party applications that exist to harden the loading of dynamic libraries, e.g. [Arxan GuardIT](https://www.arxan.com/products/).

.Net assemblies you can also be [strongly-signed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/xc31ft41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a private key, then the application will only load dlls signed signed by this key.

Comment: No they do not maintain a whitelist. I checked that https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome_elf/blacklist/blacklist.cc&l=24 . They can somehow identify a blacklisted dll even after modification...

Comment: So a cursory look at your own link reveals that the magic is in this NtMapViewOfSection Windows function. I'm not a winapi developer so can't comment on why this works, but that's what they're doing. I've added the relevant snippets to answer if you want to dig further.